# Multistore in prestashop 1.5

Tags: prestashop

I created 2 shop with:

localhost:81/prestashop/  (default) and

localhost:81/prestashop/quanao/

i write module to list all shop link into backend office.

how to get 2 above link in custom module?

Best regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will return an array with all the information:

```
Shop::getShops();
```